# Using ReactJS on Static Websites

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and want to start using it on my existing websites by changing some of my static content to be on React, like the footer content and contact, however when I use JSX the contents don't appear but if I use raw react scripts they work

This Code doesn't execute anything

```
var Footer = React.createClass({
 render:function(){
     return <a href="www.example.com">Developed by Me</a>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Footer/>,
 document.getElementById('bluevineCredits')
);
```

This code executes.

```
const title = createElement(
'a',
{
    id:'Bluevine Group',

    href:'//www.bluevinegroup.co.za'

},
'Developed and Maintained by Bluevine Group'
)

render(
title,
document.getElementById('bluevineCredits')
)
```

Comment: This is because you have to transpile your JSX code with, for example, babel. Browsers don't understand JSX

Comment: You didn't configure it properly. If you don't want to do a long way of doing it. You can use a ready one https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: My Script looks like this

<script type="text/babel" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/js/react/index.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>